# Converting to mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, converters

I have a table called SF_Data and there is a column called IN_Date, ID the data looks like:

```
ID      IN_Date
1       9/8/2010
2       26/04/2011
3       20/09/2010
```

The datatatype of IN_Date is varchar(50).

I am trying to convert the IN_Date to mm/dd/yyyy format. I tried doing this:

```
Select convert(varchar,IN_Date,103) From dbo.SF_Data
```

But still the format doesn't change. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: If it's a DATE - why isn't it `DATETIME` ?? That would make things just **soo much easier!**

Comment: @GBN  The table was created by someone else

Comment: Change the column datatype !! You'll save yourself so much grief in the long run.......

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a convert to fix the data (to the correct datatype) *before* formatting...

```
Select
     convert(varchar,
         convert(date, IN_Date, 103),
     101)
from dbo.SF_Data
```

Comment: it gives me following error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '101'.

Comment: @Peter - just missing a comma,fixed it

Comment: @Peter: Joel fixed my syntax, missing comma. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd parameter to `convert` has no meaning when converting from  `varchar` to `varchar`.  So per @marc_s' comment, you'd have to convert the `varchar` to a `datetime` using the 103 format, and then from `datetime` to `varchar` specifying the 101 format:

```
Select convert(varchar(12),convert(datetime,IN_Date,103),101) From dbo.SF_Data
```

For example:

```
select convert(varchar(12),convert(datetime,'31/12/2001',103),101)
```

prints `12/31/2001`.

[See MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Yeah - but it's a VARCHAR to begin with - it needs to be converted to a `DATETIME` first, and then back to a VARCHAR (in a different format)