# converting to yyyy/dd/mm

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a table called Raw_Data and the data looks like:

```
ID    Res_Date
1     2010-08-09 00:00:00.000
2     2010-07-09 00:00:00.000
3     2010-02-09 00:00:00.000
```

I am looking for output to be :

```
ID   Res_Date
1    2010-09-08 00:00:00.000
2    2010-09-07 00:00:00.000
3    2010-09-02 00:00:00.000
```

I tried following query;

```
Select ID,convert(datetime,Res_date,121) from Raw_data
```

but the format doesn't change. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Do you *really* want yyyy/dd/mm? That's a *very* strange format. Strange enough that it's not supported natively by SQL Server, and I don't think I've *ever* seen it. Are you sure you don't want yyyy/mm/dd? (Note that your sample data has dashes rather than slashes, too... and it would be useful if you'd pick sample dates which make it clear which is the month and which is the day...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting to mm/dd/yyyy format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248329/converting-to-mm-dd-yyyy-format)

Comment: @marc_s it is not a duplicate because the OP is looking for yyyy/dd/mm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this if you want dashes in your results

```
SELECT LEFT(convert(varchar, Res_date, 102), 4) + '-' 
    + LEFT(convert(varchar, Res_date, 105), 5) + ' '
    + RIGHT(convert(varchar, Res_date, 121), 12)
from Raw_data
```

If you want slashes:

```
SELECT LEFT(convert(varchar, Res_date, 102), 4) + '/' 
    + LEFT(convert(varchar, Res_date, 103), 5) + ' '
    + RIGHT(convert(varchar, Res_date, 121), 12)
from Raw_data
```

Here are some resources on formatting datetime

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: Though I understand this is a viable option, this is certainly the sledge-hammer on a finish nail approach.

Comment: @Brad I agree that it isn't at all pretty but he asked for a different format of yyyy-dd-mm.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting to a VARCHAR (or similar)?

A date has it's own native "tostring" for the purpose of queries/output. If you want the change to show up, it needs to be output in a string format.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), Res_date, 121)
```

Comment: the output is coming like 2010-09-08

Comment: Are you wanting it to be 2010/31/08 ?

Comment: @peter: That's because @Paul placed a hard string length limit on it. Use `varchar(100)` or just `varchar` so it doesn't truncate the results to 10 or fewer characters (as `NVARCHAR(10)` will).

Comment: @Paulstock I want the output to be 2010-09-08 00:00:00.000

Comment: formatting using 121 leaves it in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm format. The OP asks for yyyy-dd-mm